# show user input date in generated pdf ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to `ajax` and `json` and I want to display the user inputed `search_end_date` comming from `ajax` on exported pdf. I have tried different approaches but failed.
here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


    $("#search-frm").submit(function(){
        oTableCustom.draw();
        return false;
    });




    $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';
    var cur_month = '{{date("M")}}';
    
   
    var title = 'WEBPAL WEB SERVICES                                                                            BORDEROU CONTABILITATE LUNA:'+ cur_month;
    var filename = 'WEBPAL WEB SERVICES BORDEROU CONTABILITATE LUNA:'+ cur_month;
    var oTableCustom = $('#server-side-datatables').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        serverSide: true,
        searching: false,
          ajax: {
            "url": "{!! route($moduleRouteText.'.data') !!}",
            "data": function ( data ) 
            {
                data.search_start_date = $("#search-frm input[name='search_start_date']").val();
                data.search_end_date = $("#search-frm input[name='search_end_date']").val();
                data.doc_number = $("#search-frm input[name='doc_number']").val();
                data.search_parteners = $("#search-frm input[name='search_parteners']").val();
            }
        },
```

I want to display it in the `cur_month` variable declared in the starting lines

Comment: Are you using some kind of librarym what is `DataTable`?

Comment: it is where i fetch data from database